# Export To Excel a gridcontrol from devexpress with wraptext true for all columns

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, export-to-excel, gridcontrol

How to set **wraptext** true while export to excel using **devexpress** WPF grid.

I am using below code for exporting:

```
tableView.ExportToXlsx(saveFileDialog.FileName, new XlsxExportOptions(TextExportMode.Text));
```

Comment: post this question on `DevExpress support center`...

Comment: Is this thread similar to you https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T170856